# sphinx questions about searching multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sphinx

if i am trying to search "a b". a appears in column x, b appears in column y. when i do SPH_MATCH_ALL the row does not show up..

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you post your sphinx.conf file and the exact query

Answer (score 0):

[min_word_len](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-min-word-len) might be the problem here. Any word under the character threshold won't be indexed and can't be found in a search.